# Change tab names in Drupal module depending on the user Logged In.

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

Working on Intranet built on Drupal where I got a module with couple of tabs.

There are two types of users, admin and non-admins. I like to change the name of the tab depending on who is viewing it.

Currently this is what I got:

```
function lessons_learned_menu(){
...
  $items['lessons-learned/projects/viewAll'] = array(
    'title' => 'View All Projects - LL',
    'description' => 'Review page that lists projects that are currently open.',
    'page callback' => 'pmo_lessons_learned_projects_viewAll',
    'access arguments' => array('Access pmo_lessons_learned'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
  );
...
```

The access argument 'Access pmo_lessons_learned', everyone has (including Admins) and 'Administrator pmo_lessons_learned' only Admins have.

Something that didn't work:

```
if(!user_access("Administer pmo_lessons_learned")){    
   $items['lessons-learned/projects/viewAll'] = array(
     'title' => 'View All Projects - LL',
     'description' => 'Review page that lists projects that are currently open.',
     'page callback' => 'pmo_lessons_learned_projects_viewAll',
     'access arguments' => array('Access pmo_lessons_learned'),
     'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
   );
}
else
{
    $items['lessons-learned/projects/viewAll'] = array(
      'title' => 'Review Projects',
      ...
}
```

When I tried to debug it, I always got the user as Admin (when it was non-Admin), therefore went to the else condition every time.

So I like to change the name of the tab if the user is not Admin and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hook_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) is invoked once to build and cache the menu items and is not supposed to run again until the cache is cleared. This hook is invoked by Drupal user 1 (admin), this explains why `user_access("Administer pmo_lessons_learned")` returns `true`.

However you can use the `'title callback'` config in the menu items definition to generate the title with a function.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! One more question: Now I like to add a tab if the user is non-Admin and not show the tab at all for the Admin. Any ideas on how to do that? Or is there a way of saying not Administrator so only non admins see the tab. Add a NOT somewhere here?
 'access arguments' => array('Administrator pmo_lessons_learned'),

Comment: For this you need to change the `'type'` config but you can't use a callback for type, so one way is to add a menu item so there is one for non-admin and one for admin, then you will be able to set specific `title`, `access arguments` and `type`. To prevent the admin item to be rendered as a tab switch the type to 'MENU_CALLBACK'. This solution means having a different path for the admin item. 
You may prefer to alter the rendering of 'menu local task' items right from the theme via hook_preprocess implementation or template/css override.